# The form of elementary propositions in TLF

Tags: philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein, symbolic-logic

In *Tractatus* Wittgenstein states that:

> **4.22** An elementary proposition consists of names. It is a nexus, a concatenation, of names.

Suppose now that *L* is a first order language. As far as I understand the passage above an example of the elementary proposition is the following sentence of *L*:

Rabc

where R is 3-ary relation symbol of *L* and *a,b,c* are constants of *L*. This is clearly a concatenation of names and moreover, it is called by logicians *atomic formula*.

**Question.** How about sentences that contain quantifiers and variables? For example consider the following sentence.

for all **x** Q**x**

where Q is 1-ary relation symbol of *L*. Are sentences of this form elementary in view of *Tractatus*? They are puzzling for me, since they are not concatenations of names in any reasonable sense.

Comment: See *Tractatus*, 5.52-on. Basically W defines quantifiers through the N function: **N(x) = not (Exists x) fx** because **N(p,q) = not-p and not-q** and **x** ranges over all possible arguments of **f**. This amounts to: **N(x) = not-fa and not-fb and ...**

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In **5** he states that every proposition is a truth-function of elementary propositions. It seems then that a truth-function in his sense can have infinitely many arguments?  Can you please turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See *Tractatus*, 5.52-on. Basically Wittgenstein defines quantifiers through the **N** operation:

> **N(x) = not (Exists x) fx**

because **N(p,q) = not-p and not-q** [see [Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke)] and **x** ranges over all possible arguments of **f**.

This amounts to: **N(x) = not-fa and not-fb and ...**, i.e. to consider a (possibly) infinite conjunction.

In this sense, quantifiers are truth-functions.

Obviously, quantified statements are not *elementary* propositions.

Comment: I am sorry, but it seems that I mistakenly retracted my upvote to your answer. Now I cannot upvote it.